# Dynamic CRM : Create Opportunities from emails

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have to create `Opportunities` from emails. The email should be sent to a particular mail id and from that mail id CRM should be able to pick the mails and convert it to an `Opportunity`.

Please suggest the steps to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: What are your referring to when you say "mail id"? Is that an email address?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few simple steps;

- Configure your mailbox settings for incoming mails
- Create a workflow triggers when an e-mail message is created.
- Check if the message is sent or received.
- If the message is a received message, create an opportunity, you can also use the fields of the e-mail message created, such as from, subject...